# Trying to find the Return of the Jedi teaser that ran after The Empire Strikes Back in 1982

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, the-empire-strikes-back

I saw *The Empire Strikes Back* when it was first in theaters, and I saw it again when it was re-released in 1982, in anticipation of *Return of the Jedi* coming out the next year.  At the end of *Empire*, there was a teaser for *Jedi*; it may have been on the same actual reel as the *Empire* print.

Although I do not remember that much about the teaser, and I cannot find any copies of it online, I would like to find it again.  I think that it has some of the same "vertical blinds" effect that appears in this trailer for the 1982 re-release of *The Empire Strikes Back* (at 0:46 the first time it appears).

I am certain that it showed Lando Calrissian on the ground, struggling up the sand in the Sarlaac pit (although I do not think the Sarlaac's mouth and tentacles were visible behind him).  I have watched a lot of old *Return of the Jedi* promos, but none of them match what I remember.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here we go:

Search on youtube:

Return of the Jedi: Original Teaser Trailer